# IF Condition for intervals made by real numbers in bash

Tags: bash

This is a `bash` routine to compare two numbers with some defined intervals given by integers numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The comparing function
function compareInterval {
 t1=$1
 t2=$2

 shift 2

 while (( "$2" )); do
     if ((  $t1 >= $1  &&  $t2 <= $2 )); then
         # got match
         return 0
     fi
 shift 2
 done

 return 1
}

# sample values
t_initial=2
t_final=4

# Invocation. Compares against 1-3, 3-5, 2-5
if compareInterval  $t_initial $t_final  1 3  3 5  2 5; then
    echo Got match
fi
```

If the intervals are given by real numbers, i.e., `1.234`, how does the condition in the function change?

Comment: Completely, in that bash cannot compare them.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224581/floating-point-comparison-with-variable-in-bash). Short answer: use the utility `bc`.

Comment: It is not a duplicate: I want to compare the interval not the single numbers

Comment: @Py-ser Perhaps consider other languages? Of course I'd suggest Ruby.

Comment: I use python, but this is a part of a script that was ready to do something else, so I would stuck on this for this case.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you mean, something like the linked topic is useless in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new version of the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function compareInterval {
 t1=$1
 t2=$2

 shift 2

while (( $(awk -v var="$2" 'BEGIN{ if (var=="") print 0; else print 1; }') )); do
     var1=$(awk -v t1="$t1" -v t2="$1" 'BEGIN{ print (t1 >= t2) }')
     var2=$(awk -v t3="$t2" -v t4="$2" 'BEGIN{ print (t3 <= t4) }')
     if [[  "$var1" -eq "1"  &&  "$var2" -eq "1" ]]; then
         # got match
         return 0
     fi
 shift 2
 done

 return 1
}


t_initial=4399.75148230007220954256
t_final=4399.75172111932808454256
if compareInterval $t_initial $t_final 4399.48390124308 4400.47652912846 3 5 2 5; then
    echo Got match
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that the line `while (( "$2" )); do` is properly read?

Comment: @condrwasabi, I mean, with a float, is that line read without error?

Comment: I tested the code and it seems to do what you asked for. There's no error because even if `$2` is a float, testing it in the while test condition doesn't lead to any errors. The numeric comparison with the intervals range is implemented in awk (in bash you couldn't do that easily).

Comment: Just test it and see if it works for you. I'm telling you that it works for me even when I set real numbers.

Comment: I have raised the question just because I receive an error indeed :) Perhaps it is due to other lines in the script, but I receive `./script: line 28: ((: 4400.47652912846 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".47652912846 ")`. The `line 28` is the line where the `while` cycle starts and the float is `$2` in the logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57080/discussion-between-condorwasabi-and-py-ser).

Comment: New updated version. Now it should work even with real numbers in the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Just another pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

function compareInterval {
    t1=$1 t2=$2
    shift 2

    while [[ $# -ge 2 ]]; do
        is_ge "$t1" "$1" && is_le "$t2" "$2" && return 0  ## Got match.
        shift 2
    done
    return 1
}

function is_ge {
    local A1 A2 B1 B2

    if [[ $1 == *.* ]]; then
        A1=${1%%.*}
        A2=${1##*.}
    else
        A1=$1
        A2=0
    fi

    if [[ $2 == *.* ]]; then
        B1=${2%%.*}
        B2=${2##*.}
    else
        B1=$2
        B2=0
    fi

    (( L = ${#A2} > ${#B2} ? ${#A2} : ${#B2} ))

    A2=$A2'00000000000000000000'; A2=1${A2:0:L}
    B2=$B2'00000000000000000000'; B2=1${B2:0:L}

    (( A1 == B1 ? A2 >= B2 : A1 > B1 ))
}

function is_le {
    local A1 A2 B1 B2

    if [[ $1 == *.* ]]; then
        A1=${1%%.*}
        A2=${1##*.}
    else
        A1=$1
        A2=0
    fi

    if [[ $2 == *.* ]]; then
        B1=${2%%.*}
        B2=${2##*.}
    else
        B1=$2
        B2=0
    fi

    (( L = ${#A2} > ${#B2} ? ${#A2} : ${#B2} ))

    A2=$A2'00000000000000000000'; A2=1${A2:0:L}
    B2=$B2'00000000000000000000'; B2=1${B2:0:L}

    (( A1 == B1 ? A2 <= B2 : A1 < B1 ))
}

t_initial=2.4
t_final=4.5

if compareInterval "$t_initial" "$t_final" 1 3 3 5 2 5; then
    echo 'Got match.'
fi
```

Note: Of course sanity checks can be added but I find that not too necessary for now.

Comment: That's why we have bc or awk :)

Comment: @condorwasabi `bc` is an obvious reply. However I think the OP needs something that needs to be done in Bash. Forking for minor tasks also is a terrible solution commonly used by common scripters. And if you use `awk` for such purposes it's obviously a very ugly hack.

Comment: I appreciate your solution but the OP wanted a script that worked even when the interval numbers were real numbers. For example I executed your script and it crashes if t_initial or t_final are real numbers. It seems that the OP asked this question to solve this kind of potential errors.

Comment: @condorwasabi Yes looks like I had some mistakes on it. It's now fixed. By the way this `sanity check` I was referring to was about anything that could also give syntax errors to `bc` if given.