# Comparing float values in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, comparison, bc

Hi I would like to compare 2 float numbers in bash but I haven't find anything that works properly.
My actual code is the following:

```
  if [ $(echo " 0.5 > $X " | bc -l )==1 ]
  echo grande
  fi
  if [ "$(bc <<< "$X - 0.5")" > 0 ] ; then
  echo 'Yeah!'
  fi
```

What happens is that no matter if the X is bigger or smaller than 0.5, it always echos both sentences and I don't know why.
I know the X is bigger or smaller than 0.5 because I also echo it and I can see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224581/floating-point-comparison-with-variable-in-bash

Comment: when compare numeric with `[ ]` you should use `-gt` not `>`. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you need to be very careful about spacing.  For example:

```
if [ $(echo " 0.5 > $X " | bc -l )==1 ]; then
  echo grande
fi
```

Here, there are no spaces around the `==`, so it'll be interpreted as:

```
if [ 0==1 ]; then
fi
```

Believe it or not, this condition is always true.

Consider:

```
if [ "$(echo " 0.5 > $X " | bc -l )" == 1 ]; then
  echo grande
fi
```

.