# How to write if statement in .tmux.conf to set different options for different tmux versions?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, scripting, tmux

I have a .tmux.conf which I use on different machines with different tmux versions installed.

I want to set different mouse options, depending on the tmux version.
On one machine I have version `2.0` on the other `2.1`.

I do not get his part right

```
if "[[(( $(tmux -V | cut -c 6-) < 2.1 ))]]" \
  "set -g mode-mouse on;" \
  "set -g mouse-resize-pane on;" \
  "set -g select-pane on;" \
  "set -g select-window on" "set -g mouse on"
```

When I source the file

`$ tmux source-file .tmux.conf`

I get this message

`.tmux.conf:12: unknown command: set -g mouse-resize-pane on`

The machine where I run it has version `2.1` so it shouldn't set the four options.

I want to set the four options when running tmux 2.0 or less or the one option when running tmux 2.1.

This bash statement works

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.1
$ if [[(( $(tmux -V | cut -c 6-) < 2.1 ))]];then echo $?;else echo $?;fi
1
```

Comment: Why do you have both `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` in that test? I would think just `(( ))` would be enough assuming `if` (which is `if-shell`?) tests the return code.

Comment: fixing the if statement to 
`if "(( $(tmux -V | cut -c 6-) < 2.1 ))" "set -g mode-mouse on; set -g mouse-resize-pane on; set -g select-pane on; set -g select-window on"` fixes the problem, Can you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Actually `(( ))` can't handle the decimal numbers so if that works it is a different reason (or accidental). Does tmux have a way to test for features? (I assume you only want that turned on in versions that support it.)

Comment: I do not know if tmux can test for features, I am rather new to tmux.

Comment: os detect: http://superuser.com/questions/539595/tmux-configuration-conditional-to-os/539657

Comment: I just learned "the hard way" that the `[[` syntax is not supported when using `run-shell`. Well, I should've known better since the documentation says that `/usr/bin/sh` is used, and while that _probably_ means bash, it may be running in a compatibility mode, and `[[` is bash-specific. BUT, you can simply replace `[[ <expr> ]]` with `test "<expr>"` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Based on [@ericx's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1079656/365890) and [@thiagowfx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36953319/5353461) I put the following together which covers many of the [listed incompatibilties](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES) from version 2.0 onwards:

```
# Version-specific commands [grumble, grumble]
# See: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES
run-shell 'tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(tmux -V | \
                           sed -En "s/^tmux[^0-9]*([.0-9]+).*/\1/p")'

if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.1" | bc)" = 1 ]' {
    set -g mouse-select-pane on; set -g mode-mouse on
    set -g mouse-resize-pane on; set -g mouse-select-window on
    set -g message-fg red
    set -g message-bg black
    set -g message-attr bright
    set -g window-status-bg default
    set -g window-status-fg default
    set -g window-status-current-attr bold
    set -g window-status-current-bg cyan
    set -g window-status-current-fg default
    set -g window-status-bell-fg red
    set -g window-status-bell-bg black
    set -g window-status-activity-fg white
    set -g window-status-activity-bg black
}

# In version 2.1 "mouse" replaced the previous 4 mouse options
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION >= 2.1" | bc)" = 1 ]' {
    set -g mouse on
}

# UTF8 is autodetected in 2.2 onwards, but errors if explicitly set
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.2" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    set -g utf8 on
    set -g status-utf8 on
    set -g mouse-utf8 on
}

# bind-key syntax changed in 2.4 -- selection / copy / paste
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.4" | bc)" = 1 ]' {
    bind-key -t vi-copy v   begin-selection
    bind-key -t vi-copy V   send -X select-line
    bind-key -t vi-copy C-v rectangle-toggle
    bind-key -t vi-copy y   copy-pipe 'xclip -selection clipboard -in'
}

# Newer versions
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.9" | bc)" = 1 ]' {
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v   send -X begin-selection
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi V   send -X select-line
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-v send -X rectangle-toggle
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y   send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -selection clipboard -in'
}

if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION >= 2.9" | bc)" = 1 ]' {
    set -g message-style fg=red,bg=black
    set -g message-style bright
    set -g window-status-style          fg=default,bg=default
    set -g window-status-current-style  fg=default,bg=cyan,bold
    set -g window-status-bell-style     fg=red,bg=black
    set -g window-status-activity-style fg=white,bg=black
}
```

I raised an issue about the problems with `tmux`'s non-backward-compatibility [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1732). The summary is that the `tmux` devs will not support backward compatibility, nor will they adopt a version numbering scheme which highlights which versions contain breaking changes.

I raised an issue to [support numeric comparators for `%if`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1747) which was [implemented in v3.0](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES#L46).

Comment: Thanks Tom, this is great. I've added a thank you to you on my repo github.com/sixarm/sixarm_tmux_dotfiles

Comment: As someone who uses the same dotfiles on OSX and 2-3 different linux boxes, I can't thank you enough! This answer seems to be the most versatile of them all.

Comment: this is pointed out below in Micah's answer, but I was having issues due to missing semicolons here before the back slashes (it was all being interpreted as a single long command). Thanks for the example!

Comment: @TonyClifton Indeed, not only the missing semicolons cause problems, but also everything past the first comment char (`#`) was ignored in my case ...

Comment: @Griddo thanks for the edit.  I've updated based on v2.9, but as I didn't encounter the issues you experienced, I'd appreciate your review.  What version are you using which baulks at the `#` and lack of `;`?

Comment: @TomHale I'm currently using v2.6 on linux mint and also something >v2.4 as well as v2.8 on WSL debian. See [this minimal example](https://pastebin.com/4BAeGCck) which exactly reproduces the two errors.

Comment: It should be noted that these version checks will not work if there are letters and other characters in the release version. In the spirit of tmux's FU SEMVER, I offer up the last two releases on GitHub that defy these version checks: `2.9a` and `3.0-rc3`. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases

Comment: `$(tmux -V | cut -c -8 | cut -d' ' -f2)`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @danemacmillan. Their release management is FUBAR. I've updated with a single `sed -n`.

Comment: @TomHale, the `setenv` line doesn't work for version `tmux.orig 2.8` value. `sed -En "s/^tmux.* ...` does work.

Comment: @raychi Sorry, but I don't quite follow.  Please suggest an edit.

Comment: @TomHale, My `tmux -V` returns the string `tmux.orig 2.8`. This value doesn't work with the run-shell sed command. Change the sed pattern to `s/^tmux.* ....` (add .* after "tmux"). Suggest edit didn't work since change needs to be 6 characters long and mine is just 2-chars :)

Comment: The [current head of master has the version string: `tmux next-3.3`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/634a2bb647bc77c3679f63da3bf877d252b79b1f/configure.ac#L3)

The pattern in the answer didn't work, an (other) appropriate pattern for sed is: 
```bash
sed -En "s/^tmux[^0-9]*([.0-9]+).*/\1/p"
```

I read your linked issue, & I share your disappointment in the maintainers' attitude towards semver. As you pointed out, that 23 minutes of .conf fixup for one dev -> thousands of cumilative person-hours across the userbase.

Comment: Hey, just regarding this, one way to clean-up your `tmux.conf` that implements this so it's a little more DRY: 

You can store your shell test strings in tmux env vars, [(since 0.8 in 2008)](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3c1f34c/CHANGES#L2480-L2493) and interpolate them @ run time for `if-shell`:

`V33_GTE='[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION >= 3.3" | bc)" = 1 ]'`
`V33_LT='[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 3.3" | bc)" = 1 ]'`
`if "$V33_GTE" bind -N "Mouse mode off" M`

Comment: @MatthewStrasiotto Sorry, I don't follow, what repetition does this remove?

Comment: @TomHale instead of copy-pasting & evaluating the same shell test, you wind up copy pasting an env-var that stores the test & evaluating that. The benefit is marginal really

Comment: To avoid having to use `bc` (which isn't installed on some of the machines I often log into remotely) I've been doing this: `run-shell "tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(tmux -V | sed -E 's/^[^0-9]*//; s/[^0-9]*$//' | awk -F. '{ printf \"%d.%02d\", $1, $2 }')"` and then `if-shell 'bash -c "if [[ $TMUX_VERSION < 1.09 ]]; then :; else false; fi"' '...'`. That is, I format the version in a way that can be compared lexicographically, and use the regular bash `<` and `>` operators to compare them as strings. It works on tmux 1.8, 2.1 and 3.1b, but I haven't tested exhaustively.

Answer (score 28):

`if-shell` doesn't always work. Instead, I use a shell script for loading the correct version of tmux.conf:

In .tmux.conf:

```
run-shell "bash ~/.tmux/verify_tmux_version.sh"
```

In verify_tmux_version.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

verify_tmux_version () {
    tmux_home=~/.tmux
    tmux_version="$(tmux -V | cut -c 6-)"

    if [[ $(echo "$tmux_version >= 2.1" | bc) -eq 1 ]] ; then
        tmux source-file "$tmux_home/tmux_2.1_up.conf"
        exit
    elif [[ $(echo "$tmux_version >= 1.9" | bc) -eq 1 ]] ; then
        tmux source-file "$tmux_home/tmux_1.9_to_2.1.conf"
        exit
    else
        tmux source-file "$tmux_home/tmux_1.9_down.conf"
        exit
    fi
}

verify_tmux_version
```

For more details:
https://gist.github.com/vincenthsu/6847a8f2a94e61735034e65d17ca0d66

Comment: That `bc` hack is hardcore.

Comment: The configuration management is already non-trivial managing 3 configuration files. The `tmux` devs [introduce incompatibilities quite a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40902312/5353461) and will probably continue to do so. I prefer [a solution using only `.tmux.conf`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40902312/5353461) which I based on this answer.

Comment: I have tried the `if-shell` solution, but I can't find a way to detect the version numbers correctly on my 3 machines (Ubuntu 14.04 (tmux 1.8), Ubuntu 16.04 (tmux 2.1) and macOS Sierra (tmux 2.3)). So I choose to call bash directly. I would be happy if someone make "only one .tmux.conf" work.

Comment: That `bc` hack is so hardcore it fails for me: my `tmux` version is "3.0a", @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事

Can be fixed with `tmux_version="$(tmux -V | cut -c 6-8)"`

Comment: @NeilG that has nothing to do with the `bc` hack, just the `cut` part is pretty unreliable! - also your fix will break for other outputs like `tmux next-3.3` or even if just one part uses more than one digit. **||** although it gets a little bit longer, i use `sed` instead of `cut` which works for all cases known: `sed -E -e 's/[[:alpha:][:space:][:punct:]]*([[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]+).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 25):

This is kind of a hassle. The correct way to do this *within tmux* (not relying on an external shell script) combines features of both Vincent and jdloft's responses.

The `if-shell` command in tmux is used as

```
if-shell [-bF] [-t target-pane] shell-command command [command]
               (alias: if)
    Execute the first command if shell-command returns success or the second command otherwise.  Before
    being executed, shell-command is expanded using the rules specified in the FORMATS section, including
    those relevant to target-pane.  With -b, shell-command is run in the background.

    If -F is given, shell-command is not executed but considered success if neither empty nor zero (after
         formats are expanded).
```

Note that tmux shell-command expansion will expand variables of the form `#{pane_current_path}` but otherwise will leave the command alone.

More importantly, note that tmux [uses](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1.8/job.c#L87) `/bin/sh -c` to execute the shell command we specify. Thus, the command [*must be POSIX compliant*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/2514228), so tests of the form `[[` are not guaranteed to be portable. Modern Ubuntu and Debian systems, for example, symlink `/bin/sh` to `dash`.

We want to run a POSIX compliant shell command that tests the tmux version and returns 0 (true) if the desired version is found.

```
if-shell '[ $(echo "$(tmux -V | cut -d" " -f2) >= 2.1" | bc) -eq 1 ]' \
    'command if true' \
    'command if false'
```

Example:

```
if-shell '[ $(echo "$(tmux -V | cut -d" " -f2) >= 2.1" | bc) -eq 1 ]' \
    'set -g mouse on; set -g mouse-utf8 on' \
    'set -g mode-mouse on; set -g mouse-resize-pane on; set -g mouse-select-pane on; set -g mouse-select-window on'
```

This correctly deals with the fact that we are doing floating point arithmetic, so `bc` [is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224805/2514228). Additionally, there is no need for an if/then/else/fi construct, as the `[` operator produces a truthy value by itself.

A couple notes

- Lines continuing onto the next line cannot have trailing comments or tmux will give an "unknown command" error message.
- The "command if false" can be omitted.
- Multiple commands for either true or false can be combined using `;`
- The command is run on the underlying shell using `/bin/sh -c`. Other approaches that use `[[` or other non-POSIX syntax are not guaranteed to work.

**EDIT**: A previous version of this answer used `[[`, which doesn't work on systems that don't use bash. Replacing with `[` solves this.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to make this work with nested if statements.

Comment: I'm sure you could @Carl, but your quoting of `"` characters would get hairy. @pana You'll need a `;` between lines 2 and 3 in the last example. Also, you have `mouse` twice. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40902312/5353461) for an example of a continuation within a continuation.

Comment: Minor nit: `[` is not an operator, it is a command.  This is only an important distinction because many people mistake `[` as being  part of the shell grammar, which it is not.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I was able to achieve what I was after and I learned a few things about tmux and Bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I also stumbled over configuration mismatches in different tmux versions. After reviewing all the solutions here and in [this related question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1069902/tmux-configuration-stanzas-based-on-tmux-version), I've implemented the following variant:

```
# Version-specific configuration can be placed in ~/.tmux/${TMUX_VERSION}/*.conf
run-shell "for conf in ~/.tmux/$(tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2)/*.conf; do tmux source-file \"\$conf\"; done"
```

With this, version-specific configuration can be put in (multiple) configuration snippets for a particular version. This is similar to the solution of @VincentHsu, but:

- It does not require an external shell script.
- It does not segregate into fixed version ranges (... / 1.9 to 2.0 / 2.1 ...). Instead, one can use (sym)links to share a configuration snippet among multiple tmux versions.
- It does not hardcode a single filename for a version. By allowing multiple configuration snippets for each version, parts can be shared among versions while others are kept version-specific. This should offer the utmost flexibility.
- There's just a single configuration element in the original `~/.tmux.conf`. Other solutions like the one from @TomHale duplicate the version test for each configuration element.

Answer (score 8):

On some machines I was getting a false-positive result with the double bracket ('[[') syntax. So I came up with an alternative using awk:

```
# Enable mouse for different versions of tmux
# (If 'awk' exits with status 0, 'if-shell' evaluates to true)
# tmux < v2.1:
if-shell "tmux -V | awk '{exit !($2 < \"2.1\")}'" \
    "setw -g mode-mouse on ; set -g mouse-select-pane on ; set -g mouse-resize-pane on ; set -g mouse-select-window on ;"
# tmux >= v2.1:
if-shell "tmux -V | awk '{exit !($2 >= \"2.1\")}'" \
    "set -g mouse on ;"
```

Comment: Brilliant solution, that should be the accepted answer! Thanks (I'd add `head -1 |` after `tmux -V |` in case they will include more lines into its description later.)

Comment: @Krisztian Should not be necessary, as the `exit` already causes `awk` to stop processing on first line.

Comment: @raimue, thanks, I didn't know that, it seems to work indeed: `echo -e "tmux 2.0-master\ntmux 2.8" | awk '{exit !($2 < "2.1")}' && echo ok || echo no`

Answer (score 7):

Tmux's `if-shell` can be used to check the ZSH version.

```
[[ `tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2` -lt 2.1 ]]
```

checks whether or not the tmux version is greater than or equal to 2.1. Using this we can set your mouse commands depending on the ZSH version.

```
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2` -lt 2.1 ]]" \
    'set -g mode-mouse on; set -g mouse-resize-pane on; set -g mouse-select-pane on; set -g mouse-select-window on'
```

And set it for later versions of tmux:

```
if-shell "[[ `tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2` -ge 2.1 ]]" \
    'set -g mouse on; set -g mouse-utf8 on'
```

Comment: The `if-shell` configuration for tmux <2.1 seems not working. Even with tmux 2.0, the bash shell says true for
`if [[ $(tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2) -lt 2.1 ]]; then echo 'true'; true; else echo 'false'; false; fi`,
but with
`if-shell "if [[ $(tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2) -lt 2.1 ]]; then true; else false; fi" "display true;" "display false;"`,
tmux says that `unknown command: display 2`. It means the `shell` command is evaluated as false.

Comment: I get the same problem. if-shell always get false return. anyone coule please me?

Comment: This simply doesn't work. Just try running ``[[ `tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2` -lt 2.1 ]]`` in bash. I get `-bash: [[: 2.2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2")`. The reason is that these test operators don't handle floating points, for which you need `bc`.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing in Z shell which allows the use of the "-lt" operator like that. Try replacing it with the '<' symbol (and the '>' symbol for greater than).

Comment: A cat dies whenever somebody does `boolean ? true : false` instead of `boolean` only

Comment: Hey, has anyone ever got this to work?  tmux 'run-shell' is hard-coded to run /bin/sh.  None of the example above work in /bin/sh.

Comment: `sh` and `bash` don't allow for arithmetic comparison of floats. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40902312/5353461) for a solution using the bench calculator `bc`

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this issue and my solution was to write an "tmux-older-than" script:

```
#! /bin/bash

TMUX_VERSION="$(tmux -V | cut -d" " -f2)"
test 1 -eq "$( echo "$TMUX_VERSION < $1" | bc)"
```

This makes tmux.conf much more readable:

```
if-shell 'tmux-older-than 3.0' \
        'bind-key ^P swap-window -t -1' \
        'bind-key ^P swap-window -d -t -1'
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this config for many years.

- Support versions like `tmux 2.4` `tmux 2.4a` `tmux next-3.3`
- No `bc` command
- Support Cygwin, macOS and Linux

```sh
# Tmux version before 2.4
if-shell -b '[ `tmux -V | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d " |\-|.|[:alpha:]"` -lt 24 ]' \
  'bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection; \
    bind-key -t vi-copy Q cancel; \
    bind-key -t vi-copy Enter cancel'

# Tmux version 2.4 onwards
if-shell -b '[ `tmux -V | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d " |\-|.|[:alpha:]"` -ge 24 ]' \
  'bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-w   send-keys -X cancel; \
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-u   send-keys -X halfpage-up; \
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-j   send-keys -X halfpage-down; \
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-l   send-keys -X select-line'
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** some key improvements can:

- Keep good `sh` and tmux compatibility back to at least 1.8
- Free you from the `bc` requirement for portability
- Increase readability of the `if` statements
- Let you use `{}` on larger complicated nested string blocks, provided those are for 3.0 and newer

## Version check

I prefer `awk` and `sed` (core linux tools) approach to getting the version:

```
run-shell 'tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(\
             tmux -V | \
             sed -En "s/^tmux[^0-9]*([.0-9]+).*/\1/p" | \
             awk "{major=int(\$1); \
                   minor=\$1-major; \
                   print int(major*100+minor*10) }")'
```

This is very similar to solution that use string manipulation techniques, except I'm able to easily do math in `awk`.

E.g.

- `tmux 1.3` becomes `103`
- `tmux 3.2a` becomes `302`

Now instead of having to remember the `bc`/other expression every time you want to `if-shell`, it's a fairly normal `sh` expression.

```bash
'[ "${TMUX_VERSION}" -lt "200" ]' # Version < 2.0
'[ "${TMUX_VERSION}" -le "215" ]' # Version <= 2.15 (a pretend version 2.15)
```

**Note** Some ancient versions of GNU `sed` don't like `-E` flag and need `-r` instead. (BSD (darwin) doesn't support `-r`). These are all EOL and *should* no longer be a problem. But if that level of portability matters, an addition `run-shell` test could resolve that distinction.

## If-shells examples

```
if-shell -b '[ "${TMUX_VERSION}" -lt "200" ]' " \
             setw -g mode-mouse on; \
             set -g mouse-select-window on; \
             set -g mouse-select-pane on; \
             set -g mouse-resize-pane on; \
             set -g mouse-utf on"

if-shell -b '[ "${TMUX_VERSION}" -ge "200" ]' " \
             set-window-option -g mouse on"
```

## {} strings

I could not get @Tom Hale solution using `{}` to work. This appears to be a tmux 3.0 feature. Just having `}` on a line by itself will upset tmux 1.8 - 2.9, so I can't figure out how to use it.

What I found works, is if I used `'` as the outer most string quotes, then I can use {} internally, if and only if I escape it so that it is interpreted as a single line (although it will be readable as multiple lines for me)

To keep older versions of tmux happy:

- `{` and `}` must come at the end of the line, no `}` on their own
- Every line must end in `\`. The essentially means it's a single line, partially defeating the key multiline benefit of `{}`. However this still improves readability and allows easier string nesting.
- Since every line must end in `\`, multiple command will still need `;` between them when on multiple lines (See `copy-mode`  below)

**Rehash** This parses successfully on 1.8 (I never test older) and newer, as long as the tmux version check is for versions 3.0 or greater. The examples above target versions 1 and 2, so cannot use the escaped `{}` method

#### Snippet of a complicated example

```
if-shell -b '[ "${TMUX_VERSION}" -ge "300" ]' ' \
  bind-key -T root MouseDown3Pane \
    if-shell -F -t = "#{||:#{mouse_any_flag},#{&&:#{pane_in_mode},#{?#{m/r:(copy|view)-mode,#{pane_mode}},0,1}}}" \
      "select-pane -t= ; send -M" { \
        display-menu -t= -xM -yM -T \
          "#[align=centre]#{pane_index} (#{pane_id})" \
          "#{?#{m/r:(copy|view)-mode,#{pane_mode}},Go To Top,}" < "send -X history-top" \
          "#{?#{m/r:(copy|view)-mode,#{pane_mode}},Go To Bottom,}" > "send -X history-bottom" \
          "" \
          "#{?mouse_word,Search For #[underscore]#{=/9/...:mouse_word},}" C-r { \
            if -F "#{?#{m/r:(copy|view)-mode,#{pane_mode}},0,1}" \
              "copy-mode -t=" ; \
            send -Xt= search-backward "#{q:mouse_word}" \
          } \
          "#{?mouse_word,Type #[underscore]#{=/9/...:mouse_word},}" C-y { \
            copy-mode -q ; \
            send-keys -l -- "#{q:mouse_word}" \
          } \
        ... } \
'
```

**Life hack**: The outer `''` can be replaced with `{}` while you use your editor of choice for syntax highlighting, but you'll have to remember to put it back

Answer (score 1):

Current latest release is `2.9a`, which throws off many of the direct comparisons used here.

My alternative makes use of `sort -V`, which is much more robust for handling version comparisons.

Edit: A commenter points out that `sort -V` is not available in BSD `sort`, for example on native OSX. However this is still an answer that accounts for versions that aren't purely numerical.

```sh
# ver >= 2.3
[ ! "$(printf "%s\n%s" "$TMUX_VERSION" "2.3" | sort -V | head -n1)" == "$TMUX_VERSION" ]' \
    "command"

# ver > 2.3
[ ! "$(printf "%s\n%s" "$TMUX_VERSION" "2.4" | sort -V | head -n1)" == "$TMUX_VERSION" ]' \
    "command"

# ver < 2.3
[ "$(printf "%s\n%s" "$TMUX_VERSION" "2.3" | sort -V | head -n1)" == "$TMUX_VERSION" ]' \
    "command"
```

Comment: careful though, `sort -V` does not always work, for example it does not work on macOS 10.11 which uses BSD `sort`

Comment: Drats, that's a good caveat. I usually put gnu sort on my OSX machines, so I missed that. I'll add the caveat to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of tmux support neater if conditions.  The below works on tmux version 3.2a:

```
if-shell '[ "$(tmux -V)" = "tmux 3.2a" ]' {
    set -g status-bg red
    set -g status-fg yellow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have combined suggested solutions to a working one (tested on tmux 1.8 and 2.7):

```
run-shell "tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(tmux -V | cut -c 6-)"

if-shell -b '[[ "$TMUX_VERSION" < "2.6" ]]' \
  "bind w choose-tree -u"

if-shell -b '[[ "$TMUX_VERSION" < "2.2" ]]' \
  "set -g status-utf8 on"
```

Comment: your cut command isn't likely to be robust enough across different version strings. For example [`tmux -V` at the HEAD of the repo is `tmux next-3.3`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/634a2bb/configure.ac#L3). `tmux -V | cut -c 6-` gives `next-3.3`. 

Also as others have pointed out `[[ ]]` test constructs are a bash feature that's not portable across systems, as the only guaranteed shell is the POSIX compliant `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an alternative, but rather an extension to the accepted answers - (Tom Hale's answer is the most robust & complete).

For less repetition in your `.tmux.conf`, you can store your shell test strings in tmux env vars [(available since 0.8 in 2008)](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3c1f34c/CHANGES#L2480-L2493) & interpolate them at run-time for `if-shell`:

```sh
# Use which sed pattern actually works in the accepted answers
run-shell 'tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(tmux -V | sed -En "...")'

# Setup condition checks
V33_GTE='[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION >= 3.3" | bc)" = 1 ]' 
V33_LT='[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 3.3" | bc)" = 1 ]'

# So on for other versions
# ...

### Example binding
# Toggle mouse
bind m set -g mouse on  \; display 'Mouse: ON'
bind M set -g mouse off \; display 'Mouse: OFF' 

# As of 3.1 you can annotate your keybindings
# As of 3.3 you can attach a note to existing bindings without setting the binding
# If running >= 3.3 , attach a note to the binding for `list-keys -N`

if "$V33_GTE" bind -N "Enable mouse mode" m
if "$V33_GTE" bind -N "Disable mouse mode" M
```

Comment: `set -g mouse`  (without on or off) toggles all by itself.  Try this:  `bind-key c-M set-option -g mouse \; display-message 'Mouse #{?mouse,on,off}'`

Comment: I can change the answer to reflect that different approach, but it's not relevant to the answer, it's an example of a binding that's conditional on an `if-shell` statement that evaluates an interpolated statement.

Answer (score 0):

tmux 3.0a

```sh
# execute a tmux command if a shell-command succeeded
# if-shell '[[ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]' \     # use test or [ , instead of [[
# if-shell "[ $HOST == 'redmi14-leo' ]"   # can't work don't know why

if-shell '[[ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]' \
    'source-file ~/.tmux.remote.conf'
```

Comment: Comparison operator in sh is just `=`, not `==`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `set -gq` (c.f. [FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-make-tmuxconf-portable-between-tmux-versions)) to set options silently. If they are not available in older versions of `tmux`, they will just be silently ignored.

For example, this is one way to set the newly added [`allow-passthrough`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3218#issuecomment-1365063163) option, without erroring out in `tmux` versions prior to `3.3a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check `split-window` in different tmux version to solve https://github.com/christoomey/dotfiles/issues/127

try

```
run-shell 'tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(tmux -V | \
                           sed -En "s/^tmux[^0-9]*([.0-9]+).*/\1/p")'

# split panes using \ and -
# https://github.com/christoomey/dotfiles/issues/127
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION >= 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    "bind \\\\ split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'; \
"

if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    "bind \\ split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'; \
"
```

`if-shell` will re-escape `\`, so you need `\\\\`

reason: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1827#issuecomment-508985729