# Howto do floating point compasiosn in an if-statement within a GNU parallel block?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I want to run a batch process in parallel. For this I pipe a list to `parallel`. When I've an if-statement, that compares two floating point numbers (taken form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224581/floating-point-comparison-with-variable-in-bash#15224805)), the code doesn't run anymore. How can this be solved.

```
LIMIT=25

ps | parallel -j2 '   
    echo "Do stuff for {} to determine NUM"    
    NUM=33.3333 # set to demonstrate

    if (( $(echo "$NUM > $LIMIT" | bc -l) )); then
        echo "react..."
    fi

    echo "Do stuff..."
    '
```

Prints:

```
Do stuff for \ \ PID\ TTY\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ TIME\ CMD to determine NUM
Do stuff...
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
#... snipp
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Depending on what you are doing and the overhead of running external programs like `bc`, it may be faster to just do everything serially in a language with proper floating-point support.

Comment: In my real code, I call an external (serial) program that runs for 2-3 minutes (instead of `echo "react..."`). Is there no way to get this done? Do I need to put the parallel stuff in an extra shell script?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: Move `LIMIT=25` further down by 2 lines, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While GNU Parallel is designed to deal correctly with commands spanning multiple lines, I personally find that hard to read. I prefer using a function:

```
doit() {
  arg="$1"
  echo "Do stuff for $a to determine NUM"    
  NUM=33.3333 # set to demonstrate

  if (( $(echo "$NUM > $LIMIT" | bc -l) )); then
      echo "react..."
  fi

  echo "Do stuff..."
}
export -f doit

LIMIT=25
export LIMIT

ps | parallel -j2 doit
```

Instead of the exports you can use `env_parallel`:

```
ps | env_parallel -j2 doit
```

If your environment is too big, use `env_parallel --session` before starting:

```
#!/bin/bash

env_parallel --session

# Define functions and variables _after_ running --session
doit() {
  [...]
}
LIMIT=25

ps | env_parallel -j2 doit
```

Answer (score 3):

LIMIT is not set inside parallel shell. Running `echo "$NUM > $LIMIT" | bc -l` exapands to `echo "123 > " | bc -l` which results in syntax error reported by `bc`. You need to export/pass/put it's value to the shell run from inside parallel. Try this:

```
LIMIT=25
ps | parallel -j2 '   
    LIMIT="'"$LIMIT"'"
    echo "Do stuff for {} to determine NUM"    
    NUM=33.3333 # set to demonstrate

    if (( $(echo "$NUM > $LIMIT" | bc -l) )); then
        echo "react..."
    fi

    echo "Do stuff..."
    '
```

Or better use [env_parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Transferring-environment-variables-and-functions), designed for such problems.

Side note: [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) was designed for executing jobs in parallel using one **or more** computers. For scripts running on one computer it is better to stick with the xargs command, which is more commonly available (so you don't need to install some package each time you move your script to another machine).

Comment: Re: side note. Have a look at `--embed` (from 20180322).